# CakePHP REST API giving 403 for AJAX but not for cURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, cakephp

I have built a REST API using CakePHP and I'm having the following trouble.

If I execute

```
curl -v -H 'ACCEPT: application/json' -u sam:hello http://localhost/journeys/latest.json
```

I get the expected response which is:

```
{"journey":{"Journey":{"id":"17","description":null,"created":"2013-01-31 23:02:54","modified":"2013-01-31 23:02:54","user_id":"3"}}}
```

I have then attempted to incorporate this API in to some JavaScript I've written where I can request that latest journey data and then extract the id for use.

The Javascript I've written is as follows:

```
  Server.getLatestJourney = function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'http://localhost/journeys/latest.json',
    dataType: "json",
    username: 'sam',
    password: 'hello',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        latestJourney = data.journey.Journey.id;
        console.log('Laters journey id = ' + latestJourney);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log('Latest Journey error: ' + textStatus + ' Error: ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

When that piece of code executes I get the following error in the JavaScript console

```
GET http://sam:hello@localhost/journeys/latest.json 403 Forbidden 91ms
```

I am totally stumped with this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this just a static json file in webroot/journeys/latest.json? What browser are you using for testing? I also wonder if you get the same error without the username/password.

Comment: The JSON is being generated by a CakePHP controller action and I'm using Firefox on Ubuntu. The error is the same if I take away the username and password.

Comment: And hwo do you handle http authentication - with Cake AuthComponent or just in .htaccess ?

Comment: Authentication is handled by CakePHP's AuthComponent

Comment: Have you tried disabling the Auth Component to see if it will work? I can't really tell if this is an auth issue or something else. It might help to include some of the controller code and maybe you could do some debugging in the controller to make sure that the ajax request is actually hitting the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Remove option `contentType: 'application/json'` and it should work - in my REST api that was also a problem and removing this line from ajax request solved it

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't seem to have resolved the problem I'm having.

Comment: Read this http://coderseye.com/2007/how-to-do-http-basic-auth-in-ajax.html - I don't know why but as searched googe people say that setting `user` and `pass` in `$.ajax(...)` it's not working and you have to set the header manualy